# Comparing two dataframe (python pandas) by datetime intervals

Tags: python, datetime, join, pandas, merge

I need to compare two dataframe. One records events and other failures. I have to mark events that are within a range of failure.I give you an example:

df1 (events)

```
EventID arrivalTime 
3949362 22/12/2015 3:29 
3948289 22/12/2015 3:29 
3947252 22/12/2015 3:29 
3951196 22/12/2015 3:29 
3949908 22/12/2015 3:30 
3948820 22/12/2015 3:30 
3946194 22/12/2015 3:31 
3949364 22/12/2015 3:31 
3948292 22/12/2015 3:31 
3947774 22/12/2015 3:31 
3946736 22/12/2015 3:31 
3947254 22/12/2015 3:32 
3949366 22/12/2015 3:32 
3948294 22/12/2015 3:32 
3946196 22/12/2015 3:32 
3948824 22/12/2015 3:33 
3949909 22/12/2015 3:33 
3951200 22/12/2015 3:33 
3947255 22/12/2015 3:33 
3949368 22/12/2015 3:34 
3946198 22/12/2015 3:34
```

df2 (failures)

```
failures initial  end
1 22/12/2015 3:31 22/12/2015 3:33
```

I want to get the following result:

```
EventID arrivalTime interval
3949362 22/12/2015 3:29 0
3948289 22/12/2015 3:29 0
3947252 22/12/2015 3:29 0
3951196 22/12/2015 3:29 0
3949908 22/12/2015 3:30 0
3948820 22/12/2015 3:30 0
3946194 22/12/2015 3:31 1
3949364 22/12/2015 3:31 1
3948292 22/12/2015 3:31 1
3947774 22/12/2015 3:31 1
3946736 22/12/2015 3:31 1
3947254 22/12/2015 3:32 1
3949366 22/12/2015 3:32 1
3948294 22/12/2015 3:32 1
3946196 22/12/2015 3:32 1
3948824 22/12/2015 3:33 1
3949909 22/12/2015 3:33 1
3951200 22/12/2015 3:33 1
3947255 22/12/2015 3:33 0
3949368 22/12/2015 3:34 0
3946198 22/12/2015 3:34 0
```

Currently I make two nested for but I want to do it more efficiently.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a typo in your result? Because that is exactly like your original events table. Can you please confirm? Also can you please include how you tried to solve this problem and where you got stuck?

Comment: correct there is an error the event interval value 3951200 = 1.

Comment: I currently use a function. I enter data by hand failures. I'm learning pandas and vectorization. I am translating my code to pandas. This is my function:

Comment: How would it be if I have more than one failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for change rows to column, then add missing data between `initial` and `end` by [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) and last [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df2 = df2.stack().reset_index(level=1)
df2 = df2.drop('level_1', axis=1)
df2.columns = ['Failuredate']
print df2
          Failuredate
0 2015-12-22 03:31:00
0 2015-12-22 03:33:00

#resample and fill missing data 
df2 = df2.groupby(df2.index).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Failuredate').
                      resample('1min', how='first',fill_method='ffill')).reset_index(level=1)
print df2
          Failuredate
0 2015-12-22 03:31:00
0 2015-12-22 03:32:00
0 2015-12-22 03:33:00
```

```
df1['interval'] = np.where(df1['arrivalTime'].isin(df2['Failuredate']), 1, 0)
print df1
    EventID         arrivalTime  interval
0   3949362 2015-12-22 03:29:00         0
1   3948289 2015-12-22 03:29:00         0
2   3947252 2015-12-22 03:29:00         0
3   3951196 2015-12-22 03:29:00         0
4   3949908 2015-12-22 03:30:00         0
5   3948820 2015-12-22 03:30:00         0
6   3946194 2015-12-22 03:31:00         1
7   3949364 2015-12-22 03:31:00         1
8   3948292 2015-12-22 03:31:00         1
9   3947774 2015-12-22 03:31:00         1
10  3946736 2015-12-22 03:31:00         1
11  3947254 2015-12-22 03:32:00         1
12  3949366 2015-12-22 03:32:00         1
13  3948294 2015-12-22 03:32:00         1
14  3946196 2015-12-22 03:32:00         1
15  3948824 2015-12-22 03:33:00         1
16  3949909 2015-12-22 03:33:00         1
17  3951200 2015-12-22 03:33:00         1
18  3947255 2015-12-22 03:33:00         1
19  3949368 2015-12-22 03:34:00         0
20  3946198 2015-12-22 03:34:00         0
```

Answer (score 0):

This function that I used before vectorization.

```
def periodofailure(df, failure):

    l1 = []

    if failure == 'no':
        l1 = ['no' for n in range(len(df))]
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(l1)
        frames = [df, df1]
        df = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
        df.rename(columns={0:'Incidencia'}, inplace=True)
        return df

    elif failure == 'si':
        # here I manually put failures
        IFfailure1 = str('2015-12-02 06:30:00')
        EFfailure1 = str('2015-12-02 06:42:00')
        IFfailure2 = str('2015-12-10 18:53:00')
        EFfailure2 = str('2015-12-10 19:05:00')
        IFfailure3 = str('2015-12-11 21:18:00')
        EFfailure3 = str('2015-12-12 00:09:00')
        IFfailure4 = str('2015-12-15 11:45:00')
        EFfailure4 = str('2015-12-15 12:17:00')
        IFfailure5 = str('2015-11-18 12:28:00')
        EFfailure5 = str('2015-11-18 12:59:00')

        for index, row in df.iterrows():

            if IFfailure1 <= df['arrivalTime'][index] <= EFfailure1:
                l1.append('si')
            elif IFfailure2 <= df['arrivalTime'][index] <= EFfailure2:
                l1.append('si')
            elif IFfailure3 <= df['arrivalTime'][index] <= EFfailure3:
                l1.append('si')
            elif IFfailure4 <= df['arrivalTime'][index] <= EFfailure4:
                l1.append('si')
            elif IFfailure5 <= df['arrivalTime'][index] <= EFfailure5:
                l1.append('si')
            else:
                l1.append('no')

        df1 = pd.DataFrame(l1)
        frames = [df, df1]
        df = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
        df.rename(columns={0:'Incidencia'}, inplace=True)
        return df
```